# Breeze's executeQuery is much slower in IE11 than Chrome

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11, breeze

I have an application using BreezeJs that works great on Chrome.

But when I test it on IE, the BreezeJs executeQuery takes much longer to run.

For example, a query running on Chrome takes 86 milliseconds to run.  The **exact same query** against the **exact same service** when run on IE takes **443** milliseconds to run.

This is continually repeatable and does not matter which one runs first.

Is this just because Chrome is a faster browser?

**And more importantly, is there anything I can do to get IE11 closer to Chrome's runtimes?**

Just incase it is useful, here is what my code looks like that makes this call:

```
private getEntity<TEntityInterface extends breeze.Entity>(query: breeze.EntityQuery): Promise<TEntityInterface> {
    let startTime = performance.now();
    let queryPromise = new Promise<TEntityInterface>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.entityManager.executeQuery(query).then(queryResult => {
            let stopTime = performance.now();
            console.debug(`getEntity Time ${stopTime - startTime}`);
            if (queryResult && queryResult.results && queryResult.results.length > 0) {
                let result = <TEntityInterface>queryResult.results[0];
                resolve(<any>result);
            } else
                throw Error('Error retreiving entity');
        }).catch(error => {
                let errorMessage = 'Failed to get value from Database';
                this.queryFailed(errorMessage, error);
                reject(errorMessage);
            });
    });
    return queryPromise;
}
```

UPDATE: I tested running using just a JQuery Ajax call, and the call times were similar between IE11 and Chrome.  So this seems to just be a Breeze JS issue.

My guess is that Breeze is just doing so much javascript under the hood that IE11 can't do it fast, but Chrome can.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that Bluebird (what I am using for Promises) was getting long stack traces.  That was very slow in IE11.

I turned off [long stack traces](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.longstacktraces.html) in my project and the speed is now acceptable.